# Unit test for type and type of contents simultaneously in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

Let's say I have a function like so:

```
def f(x):
    return (1, 2, 3)
```

If I want to unit test that the return type is a tuple, I can use assertIsInstance() like so:

```
class TestF(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_return_type(self):
        result = f(10)
        self.assertIsInstance(result, tuple, "Must return tuple")
```

What if I want to check that f returns a tuple of exactly 3 integers? Obviously I can separately check the length and contents of the return with additional tests, but is there a tidier way to do this? Something like:

```
def test_return_type(self):
    result = f(10)
    self.assertIsInstance(result, (int, int, int), "Must return a tuple of 3 ints")
```

Is there something built-in that would let me do this without additional work?

Comment: Nope.  You'll need multiple asserts.

Comment: In general you can write new assertion methods if you want to, wrapping the existing methods for your own more specific needs. E.g. `self.assertNTupleOf(result, 3, int, "...")`.